# OrangeBits extension for WebMatrix may have caused a crash and has been disabled

Tags: css, less, webmatrix

I'm getting the following error every time I open WebMatrix with the OrangeBits extension installed:

The "OrangeBits" extension may have caused a crash and has been disabled. We recommend contacting the extension owner for assistance.

```
System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. ---> Ionic.Zip.ZipException: The file C:\USERS\NAME\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\WEBMATRIX\EXTENSIONS\30\OrangeBits\Tools\bin\cake already exists.
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.CheckExtractExistingFile(String baseDir, String targetFileName)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.InternalExtract(String baseDir, Stream outstream, String password)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.Extract(String baseDirectory)
   at OrangeBits.OrangeBits.<>c__DisplayClass17.<UnpackModules>b__15()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Ionic.Zip.ZipException: The file C:\USERS\NAME\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\WEBMATRIX\EXTENSIONS\30\OrangeBits\Tools\bin\cake already exists.
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.CheckExtractExistingFile(String baseDir, String targetFileName)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.InternalExtract(String baseDir, Stream outstream, String password)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.Extract(String baseDirectory)
   at OrangeBits.OrangeBits.<>c__DisplayClass17.<UnpackModules>b__15()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing Justin Beckwith's [answer here](http://extensions.webmatrix.com/packages/OrangeBits)

Resolving this issue was as simple as navigating to:

C:\USERS\NAME\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\WEBMATRIX\EXTENSIONS\30\OrangeBits\Tools

And deleting modules.zip